# Java: ClassNotFoundException on class from external jar being instantiated in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jar

I have made a library and exported it to a jar file that I am trying to import into my eclipse project and use. Eclipse says there's no problems but when I debug the application, it enters the new thread and goes to instantiate the object but then throws a `ClassNotFoundException`

> ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).(String, Throwable) line: 217 
>   ClassNotFoundException(Exception).(String, Throwable) line: not
>   available  ClassNotFoundException.(String) line: not available
>   URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available
>   AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction,
>   AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method] 
>   Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not
>   available  Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(String) line: not
>   available  Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String,
>   boolean) line: not available
>   Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line:
>   not available  Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean)
>   line: not available
>   Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not
>   available  HKServiceListener.run() line: 33    Thread.run() line: not
>   available

The class it's not finding is `com.snow.IO.SnowTcpServer`. I have included the external jar in my class path and have no compile errors. It only throws at runtime. I even have `import com.snow.IO.SnowTcpServer` at the top of the file like it should.

Why is it not recognizing my class and how do I get it to do so?

Comment: can you provide the command you are using to run ?

Comment: I am running it from Eclipse. I just hit the Run as Java Application button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the error was only caused when using the debugger. It had to do with the fact that the code I was stepping into was in an external jar file and not in my source.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with your classpath there is no other reason why classload can't find file with your class, try to run your class (compiled class) manually  without eclipse using command line

```
java -cp [your jars separated with ";" - widows or ":" - *nix] com.your.Class
```

For example:

```
java -cp /libs/lib1.jar:/libs2/* com.your.Class
```

Comment: When I tried this, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hakyn/srv/HKListener` Which is the class with my main method. I used: `C:\Users\ryan\workspace\hakyn-server>java -cp Snow.jar;mongo-2.7.2.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.1.jar;C:/Users/ryan/workspace/hakyn-server/src/* com.hakyn.srv.HKListener`

Comment: Because you should point your classpath to compiled classes (*.class) but not source code : C:/Users/ryan/workspace/hakyn-server/src/*

Comment: Ahh, I tried with the bin directory. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Enterprise application, please make sure, the Jar is available for deployment also. This needs to be configured additionally.
In case of J2SE application, please check if your jar is visible in run_configuration properties, classpath tab.

If this does not work, then try including the jar file in class path option in the run_configurations option explicitly.

Comment: The jar is already in my classpath when i looked in run_configurations.